# How do I make the SELECT tag to change the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So i have this SELECT tags here

```
<select id="url">
  <option id="url1" >url 1</option>
  <option id="url2" >url 2</option>
</select>
<button onclick="go()">GO</button>
```

Then a script here

```
<script>
function go() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'url1.php?check=' + value,
                    type: 'GET',
                    async: true,
                })
```

Now, I want to change the line of code that says: `url: 'url1.php?check=' + value,` to say whatever the selected option's `id` is rather than the hardcoded `"ur1.php"`. How do I achieve these?

NOTE: I cut the code if you're wondering why is it like that.

Comment: I don't see any attempt to read the current value of the select. Why not try something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working demo of what you need. I changed the following to make it work:

1) give your `<option>` tags `value` attributes (as per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)) rather than `id`s. The one relating to the chosen option is then automatically read as being the value of the `<select>`.

2) get the currently selected URL value by using [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of the `<select>`

3) (non-essential but good practice) using an unobtrusive event handler in the script itself rather than an inline "onclick".

4) (non-essential) you don't need `async:true` because that's already the default value.

```js
var value = "something";

$("#go").click(function() {
  var url = $("#url").val() + '.php?check=' + value;
  console.log(url);
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="url">
  <option value="url1">url 1</option>
  <option value="url2">url 2</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="go">GO</button>
```

Comment: Hi what I want is to happen is like these but it doesn't work please help
var url = '$("#url").val();' + '.php?check=' + value,

that is the variable  I want

Comment: Oh right I see, I thought the `value` was the thing you wanted to change. Where does `value` come from, then?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is to give each of your `option`'s a `value` attribute. You can the get the `select`-element and get it's value (which will be the value of the selected option)

I added some code to help you:

```js
function go() {
  const select = document.getElementById('select');
  const value = select.value; // <-- this here is the value you can use to make your request
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="url1">URL 1</option>
  <option value="url2">URL 2</option>
</select>

<button onclick="go()">Go</button>
```

Comment: For example I have a variable

    var x = myurl;

How do I replace the url  by calling the variable ? 

     $.ajax({
                        url: 'urlselect.php?check=' + value,
                        type: 'GET',
                        async: true,
            })

Answer (score -3):

HTML Code:

```
<SELECT id="url">
<option id="url1" >url 1</option>
<option id="url2" >url 2</option>
</SELECT>
<button id = "button_go">GO</button>
```

Script:

```
$("#button_go").click(go);

function go() {
  var value =$('#url').children("option:selected").attr('id');
  alert("You have selected the ID- " + value);

  // your ajax code 
}
```

Check the jsfiddle working code : https://jsfiddle.net/1eq29w6a/4/